# Powershell console not updating with latest Windows Management Framework installs

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I am using Windows 7 SP 1 64 bit. When I installed Windows Management Framework 4, the nice new blue consoles have not been installed.

I even further upgraded to Windows Management Framework 5 and am still stuck with the old black console `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.`

This powershell.exe is showing a version number of 10.0.10586.117.

Powershell has been updated though. When I enter `$PSVersionTable` in the old console window I get the following:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Everything seems to work OK.

I'm just upset that I don't have the blue Windows Powershell Console and Windows Powershell Console ISE in Accessories. Am I being too sensitive?

Is it something to do with my pre-existing install of .NET 4.6? I read somewhere that this can cause issues with Powershell installations.

Comment: Just add the shortcuts yourself to "Accessories".

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill from where? Looking at my old PC, I can see those shortcuts do point to the same exe I mentioned in my Post. But why are they different consoles (i.e. blue backgrounds) and one of them is the ISE console?

Comment: They should be pointing to **different** exes, one to `powershell.exe` and the other to `%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe`

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok got it. Thanks. I'm new here. Do you want to put this as an answer and I'll mark it as such?

Comment: The first is a plain "command line powershell", the second is the Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I don't have the Powershell Console and the Powershell Console ISE in Accessories

I don't either (on Windows 7 64bit).

You can just add two shortcuts yourself to "Accessories":

- `powershell.exe` (command line PowerShell)
- `PowerShell_ISE.exe` (PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE))

The easiest way to do this is to browse to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`, right click on the two executables, create shortcuts, then move the shortcuts to "Accessories".